# Microsoft office is crashing my computer

Tags: laptop, microsoft-office, windows-11, crash, microsoft

I've got an interesting issue on my hands and I'm normally very tech savvy and can remedy my own issues. That being said I noticed that my laptop was starting to "gracefully crash". The screen will go black and and after 3-5 seconds it will return on the lock screen. This issue happens at random intervals it seems. I feel like all I'm finding is red herrings.

What I've tried:

- I've tried disabling the Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant which I thought solved it in the terms of preventing crashes but as of today (08/13/2023) it happened without the service being enabled. Thus bringing me back to the drawing board.
- Converted Microsoft account to local account and it appears to stop the issue but is still logging {1} at an alarming rate.
- Image repair from windows media source tool
- Windows Repair tool integrated.
- "Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" followed by a "sfc/scannow" (Check log {2})
- I originally thought it was the screen failing but learned it happened on another screen over HDMI.
- I started searching through the logs and noticed it was handling power events but there still wasn't a cause that I could find so I ran a power report and checked for a failing power source. Power source checks out, battery health is good, charger is in good order, no over usage of power and no lack of power in charging.
- I eventually found an system log that was reporting an error on signing into the Microsoft accounts on this system (Look below for log {1}). The service Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant is linked to this log and when disabled I thought it stopped the problem completely but turns out to not be true.
- I tried reinstalling all Microsoft office programs and I haven't even signed into the software before it started crashing again.

Logs:

1. `Log Name: Microsoft-Windows-ModernDeployment-Diagnostics-Provider/ManagementService Source: ModernDeployment-Diagnostics-Provider Event ID: 1010 Autopilot.dll WIL error was reported. HRESULT: 0x80070491 File: onecoreuap\admin\moderndeployment\autopilot\dll\dllmain.cpp, line 128 Message: NULL`
2. `Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time. Beginning verification phase of system scan. Verification 100% complete. Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

My goal is to use Microsoft office applications still but I am prevented from doing this it seems while the Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant is disabled.

Any suggestions or even a hunch would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see no evidence this issue is connected to your account being linked to a Microsoft Account. The error being thrown has little to do with the Microsoft Store. Authentication to the Microsoft Account with a Office 365 subscription and you being logged into Microsoft Store within Windows has always been separate

Comment: @Ramhound when disabling the Microsoft sign-in assistant service in services.msc it stops the issue completely and stops logging errors.

Comment: You have some additional information contained within temporary commentary that should be added to your question.

Comment: Hi @Ramhound what information do I need added to the original post? I want ensure everyone has a full picture of the issue, sorry. I think the Microsoft store mention was misspoken. I think they intended to say Microsoft office applications and Microsoft account. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Some reports say that this problem is fixed by converting into
a local Windows login, and this has also solved the problem for the poster.
The reason why this "solution" works is unknown.

This won't prevent you from logging into the Microsoft Store with your Microsoft account.